# Adding distinct to a flutter moor query

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I have the following flutter moor query

```
(select(recipeGarnishes)..where((tbl) => tbl.postGarnish.equals(true))).get();
```

How would I add the `distinct` condition to the query?

Update:
The query I want to write is:

```
select DISTINCT garnishName from RecipeGarnishes where postGarnish = 'true'
```

`garnishName` and `postGarnish` are columns in my `RecipeGarnishes` table

Update 2:

Based on the answer, I tried this.

```
final query = selectOnly(recipeGarnishes, distinct: true)
                ..addColumns([recipeGarnishes.garnishName])
                ..where(recipeGarnishes.postGarnish.equals(postGarnish));
List<TypedResult> result = await query.get();

return result.map((row) => row.readTable(recipeGarnishes)).toList();
```

But it gives me the following error

> Moor: Sent SELECT DISTINCT recipe_garnishes.garnish_name AS "recipe_garnishes.garnish_name" FROM recipe_garnishes WHERE recipe_garnishes.post_garnish = ?; with args [1]
>
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'garnishName' was called on null.

Comment: if `distinct` is not supported you can always use `groupBy`

Comment: It does seem to support it, I just can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: this is what  documentation says:  https://pub.dev/documentation/moor/latest/moor/SimpleSelectStatement/distinct.html

Comment: but how do I use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query itself is correct, but you can't read the result like that: `row.readTable` would return a full row with all columns. However, you only select a single column (`garnishName`), so moor can't load the row and returns `null` instead.

You can use

```dart
final query = selectOnly(recipeGarnishes, distinct: true)
                ..addColumns([recipeGarnishes.garnishName])
                ..where(recipeGarnishes.postGarnish.equals(postGarnish));

return query.map((row) => row.read(recipeGarnishes.garnishName)).get();
```

Comment: Got it, thanks man. Loving the package, looking forward to using it in moor of my projects in the future :P  :D

Comment: @simolus3 is it possible to return a map?

Answer (score 1):

You can add distinct as follows

```
(select(recipeGarnishes, distinct: true)..where((tbl) => tbl.postGarnish.equals(true))).get();
```

Comment: I need to add distinct condition to the garnishName column, not the entire row.

Comment: For getting only particular columns, you can use selecyOnly instead of select, and using addColumns method. Otherwise, you can also use customSelect to enter your own query.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with the selectOnly. Still getting an error :(